# Validation issues for DateTime in cloud

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Asp Mvc 5 app with a form. The form has a text field for date & time in format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm". The validation works fine when I run it locally. However, it fails when I deploy it to Azure.

The field is generated in the view like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateField, "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH:mm}", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
```

The annotation of the ViewModel looks as follows:

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "...", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DisplayName("Date & time")]
        public DateTime DateField { get; set; }
```

Also, in the main web.config I have:

```
  <system.web>
       <globalization culture="pl-PL" uiCulture="pl-PL" />
  </system.web>
```

Since my form is inside an Area I've also added same setting inside the area-specific web.config.

Comment: Shouldn't your `DataType` be `DataType.DateTime`? Seems like a bit of a conflict to use `DataType.Date` in conjunction with that`DataFormatString`. Also, I don't think the single quotes are necessary in the `DataFormatString`.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem. Although the format clearly says dd/MM, i.e, day first then month, it still uses month first then day. To resolve the issue, I used the format below that worked very well.

> yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm

Also you can use `datetime-local` control which will render a calendar including the time potion as well. Take note that this control is supported by certain browsers only including Chrome.

> `<input type="datetime-local">`

Comment: This is a known drawback with dates. How else do you intend to address this?